# CSS - Short border line?

Tags: css

I have a border on a couple of DIVs that is only on the left side.

**CSS:**

```
#Mid-Content_ {

    position: absolute;
    left: 510px;
    top: 119px;
    height: 70%;
    border-left: #CCC 2px solid;
    width: 250px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

The border goes from the top to the bottom of the left side which is exactly what it should do according to the CSS code.

Is there a way to make it shorter, say 10px from the top and bottom? The problem is that the  text inside the DIV needs to be inline with this border line.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6w4tY/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="contentArea">
         <div id="border"></div>
         text text text text text text text text text text
</div>
```

CSS

```
   #contentArea {
     height: 100px;
     width: 80px;
     position: relative;
     background: #3beadc;
     padding:5px;
     }

   #border  {
     border-left: 2px solid #f51c40;
     position: absolute;
     top: 10px;
     bottom: 10px
     left:0px;
   }
```

If you want the border to be outside the contentArea, change its left value to *negative**border width* e.g. `left:-2px;` in the case above

Answer (score 5):

Building on the answer by @SW4 you can also use a pseudo element and then you don't have to change the html:

HTML

```
    <div id="Mid-Content_">
     text text text text text text text text text text
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  #Mid-Content_ {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  #Mid-Content_:after {
   content: "";
   border-left: #CCC 2px solid;
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 0px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, borders will always extend the full length or width of the element (e.g. content + padding, but not margin).  However you could always enclose the text inside the `div` in a `p` tag, which is semantically correct anyway, and add the border to that instead:

```
#Mid-Content_ p {
    padding: 0;
    border-left: 2px solid #CCC;
}
```

Also, the border on the `div` should be inline with the text anyway (or it would be if you didn't set an explicit height on the div), presuming you have a normal-ish `line-height` and there is no top or bottom padding on the div.

Comment: Thank you. Although the content is a few headers, images and texts. I have found I will need to add another DIV with the border instead.